# Using Eclipse CDT code analysis tools to build a plug-in

Tags: eclipse, plugins, static-analysis, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-cdt

I want to build a plug-in that uses tools like the AST from the CDT,
to perform static code analysis on a c++ source code files.
Does anyone knows something similar I can look at?
Where can I find a good tutorial to help me do that?

Thank you

Comment: If you get no good answers here, try cdt-dev mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm referring old documentation as new CDT doc is MIA from help.eclipse.org)

1. Looks like, to access AST, you should start with [CoreModelUtil::findTranslationUnit(IFile)](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/cdt/core/model/CoreModelUtil.html#findTranslationUnit%28IFile%29)
2. Make sure to check Codan - it's framework for static code analysis. You can start with org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.checker extension point.

I would really recommend to start with cloning CDT repo and adding CDT sources as projects - CDT itself is pretty much the only example on using CDT APIs.